# How to feed windowed dataset into StringLookup layer in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, time-series, tensorflow-datasets

If I have the following data and want to use `StringLookup` for preprocessing:

```
x = pd.DataFrame({'col1': list('abcdefghij'), 'col2': np.arange(10), 'col3': np.arange(10)})
y = np.arange(10)
```

First, I need to transform my windowed dataset to a dictionary of tensors as the model expects tensors as input (maybe there are better ways to do it?):

```
window_size = 3

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(x), y)).window(window_size, shift=1, drop_remainder=True)

# Extra preprocessing to get dict of tensors
dataset = dataset.flat_map(
    lambda x, y: tf.data.Dataset.zip(({k: v.batch(window_size) for k, v in x.items()}, y.batch(window_size)))
    )
dataset = dataset.batch(3)

for i, j in dataset.take(1):
  print(i, j)
```

Output:

```
{'col1': <tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 3), dtype=string, numpy=
array([[b'a', b'b', b'c'],
       [b'b', b'c', b'd'],
       [b'c', b'd', b'e']], dtype=object)>, 'col2': <tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 3), dtype=int64, numpy=
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 4]])>, 'col3': <tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 3), dtype=int64, numpy=
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 4]])>} tf.Tensor(
[[0 1 2]
 [1 2 3]
 [2 3 4]], shape=(3, 3), dtype=int64)
```

Create preprocessor for different dtypes like in this [example](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/pandas_dataframe#full_example):

```
inputs = {'col1': tf.keras.Input(shape=(), name='col1', dtype=tf.string),
          'col2': tf.keras.Input(shape=(), name='col2', dtype=tf.float32),
          'col3': tf.keras.Input(shape=(), name='col3', dtype=tf.float32)}

vocab = sorted(set(x['col1']))
lookup = tf.keras.layers.StringLookup(vocabulary=vocab, output_mode='one_hot')
lookup = lookup(inputs['col1'][:tf.newaxis])

numeric = tf.stack([tf.cast(inputs[i], dtype=tf.float32) for i in ['col2', 'col3']], axis=-1)
result = tf.concat([lookup, numeric], axis=-1)

preprocessor = tf.keras.Model(inputs, result)

# Test preprocessor
preprocessor(dict(x))
```

Output:

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(10, 13), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 2., 2.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 3., 3.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 4., 4.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 5., 5.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 6., 6.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 7., 7.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 8., 8.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 9., 9.]],
      dtype=float32)>
```

Create model:

```
body = tf.keras.models.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Dense(8),
                                   tf.keras.layers.Dense(window_size)])
x = preprocessor(inputs)
result = body(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, result)
model.summary()
```

Output:

```
Model: "model"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                   Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
 col1 (InputLayer)              [(None,)]            0           []                               
                                                                                                  
 col2 (InputLayer)              [(None,)]            0           []                               
                                                                                                  
 col3 (InputLayer)              [(None,)]            0           []                               
                                                                                                  
 model_35 (Functional)          (None, 13)           0           ['col1[0][0]',                   
                                                                  'col2[0][0]',                   
                                                                  'col3[0][0]']                   
                                                                                                  
 sequential_19 (Sequential)     (None, 3)            139         ['model_35[2][0]']               
                                                                                                  
==================================================================================================
Total params: 139
Trainable params: 139
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

Compile and train:

```
model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(dataset)
```

Error:

```
ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "string_lookup_24" (type StringLookup).

When output_mode is not `'int'`, maximum supported output rank is 2. Received output_mode one_hot and input shape (None, None), which would result in output rank 3.

Call arguments received:
  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, None), dtype=string)
```

How should I build my preprocessor or preprocess my dataset to make it work? Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work for you:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

x = pd.DataFrame({'col1': list('abcdefghij'), 'col2': np.arange(10), 'col3': np.arange(10)})
y = np.arange(10)
window_size = 3

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(x), y)).window(window_size, shift=1, drop_remainder=True)

# Extra preprocessing to get dict of tensors
dataset = dataset.flat_map(lambda window_x, window_y: tf.data.Dataset.zip({**{k: v.batch(window_size) for k, v in window_x.items()}, **{"y": window_y.batch(window_size)}}))
dataset = dataset.map(lambda data_dict: ({k: v for k, v  in data_dict.items() if k != 'y'}, data_dict["y"]))

vocab = sorted(set(x['col1']))
lookup = tf.keras.layers.StringLookup(vocabulary=vocab, output_mode='one_hot')
dataset = dataset.map(lambda i, j: ({'col1': lookup(i['col1']), 'col2': i['col2'], 'col3': i['col3']}, j)).batch(3)
```

Your model:

```
inputs = {'col1': tf.keras.Input(shape=(window_size, lookup.vocabulary_size()), name='col1', dtype=tf.float32),
          'col2': tf.keras.Input(shape=(3,), name='col2', dtype=tf.float32),
          'col3': tf.keras.Input(shape=(3,), name='col3', dtype=tf.float32)}

numeric = tf.stack([inputs['col2'], inputs['col2']], axis=-1)
result = tf.concat([inputs['col1'], numeric], axis=-1)

preprocessor = tf.keras.Model(inputs, result)

body = tf.keras.models.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
                                   tf.keras.layers.Dense(8),
                                   tf.keras.layers.Dense(window_size)])
x = preprocessor(inputs)
result = body(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, result)
model.summary()

model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(dataset)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. It looks like you moved the lookup part out from the model to the dataset.

Comment: No problem. Have fun.

Comment: Isn't the same if i simply one-hot encode input to a Dataset? I thought it would be more efficient to lookup in the model.

Comment: Ne not necessarily..

Answer (score 2):

We can completely leave out the preprocessing layer and use the `StringLookup` layer in Dataset:

```
lookup_cols = ["col1"]

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(x), y)).window(
    window_size, shift=1, drop_remainder=True
)

lookups = {
    col: tf.keras.layers.StringLookup(
        vocabulary=sorted(set(x[col])), output_mode="one_hot"
    )
    for col in lookup_cols
}

dataset = dataset.flat_map(
    lambda x, y: tf.data.Dataset.zip(
        ({k: v.batch(window_size) for k, v in x.items()}, y.batch(window_size))
    )
)

dataset = dataset.map(
    lambda x, y: (
        tf.concat(
            [
                tf.concat(
                    [lookups[k](v) for k, v in x.items() if k in lookup_cols], axis=-1
                ),
                tf.stack(
                    [
                        tf.cast(v, dtype=tf.float32)
                        for k, v in x.items()
                        if k not in lookup_cols
                    ],
                    axis=-1,
                ),
            ],
            axis=-1,
        ),
        y,
    )
)

dataset = dataset.batch(3)

for i, j in dataset.take(1):
  print(i, j)
```

Output:

```
tf.Tensor(
[[[0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1.]
  [0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 2. 2.]]

 [[0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1.]
  [0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 2. 2.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 3. 3.]]

 [[0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 2. 2.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 3. 3.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 4. 4.]]], shape=(3, 3, 13), dtype=float32) tf.Tensor(
[[0 1 2]
 [1 2 3]
 [2 3 4]], shape=(3, 3), dtype=int64)
```